# Partial template specialization - passing types as arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, rtti

I'm a trying to write a wrapper around calls of the form `typeid()==typeid()` to prevent passing pointers / pointer types as arguments (an error easily made and difficult to detect).

So where now the call would be `typeid(ClassA)==typeid(arg)`, I would like to replace it with `safesametype(ClassA, arg)` or something similar. Then, it should be checked at compile time whether none of the two arguments in fact refer to pointers.

Using functionality of the Loki library, I got almost there, but not quite. I am currently able to do the call `safesametype<ClassA, SuperClassOfA>(arg)` where `SuperClassOfA` is the type of `arg`.

Does anyone have ideas on how I can drop the `SuperClassOfA` specification? This is the current source:

```
#include "loki/NullType.h"
#include "loki/TypeTraits.h"
#include "loki/static_check.h"
#include <typeinfo>

class CannotCompareTypeIDofPointers{};

template<class T, class T2>
bool safesametype(const T& object){
    LOKI_STATIC_CHECK(not Loki::TypeTraits<T>::isPointer, InvalidTypeIDCheck);
    LOKI_STATIC_CHECK(not Loki::TypeTraits<T2>::isPointer, InvalidTypeIDCheck);
    return typeid(object)==typeid(T2);
}
```

thanks in advance!

Broes

(PS please no solutions telling me not to use `typeid`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just swap the template parameters.

```
template <class TestType, class ArgType>
bool instanceof(const ArgType& object) {
    // checks here
    return typeid(TestType) == typeid(object);
}
```

Call as:

```
instanceof<ClassA>(arg)
```